# Get a 403 error on cookie save with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, http-status-code-403

When I save a cookie with an encoded object inside, my browsers (both Chrome and Firefox) throw a 403 error on the page refresh. Things go back normal when I delete the cookie.

My code :

```
var myObject = {test:true, test2:false};
var exdays = 1;
var cname = "save";
var cvalue = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myObject));
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
```

Where am I wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: The HTTP Status code must be sent by server. The current cookies code is fine but when this cookie is sent to server, it sends 'Forbidden' status code. There must be some conditions or code on the server that encounter an error. Please be more specific.

Comment: The server runs on Plesk. Do you think some security rules can be the cause of the issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Plesk. But you should add server side code to your question also so that any one who wants to help can know what is happening on server side.

Comment: By server side code you mean logs ?

Comment: ok. I checked the error logs and you were right: ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403. My ModSecurity reeeeally dislike objects in cookies.

Comment: By the way thank you as you lead me to the solution.